# How can I fix my selenium and geckodriver bug on Cloud9?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, cloud9

**I want to fix my selenium and geckodriver bug on Cloud9 using capybara and launchy.**

When I tried to feature tests using Rspec, the errors occurred.

The errors said that

```
Failure/Error: visit root_path
     Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
       not a file: "/home/ubuntu/bin/geckodriver"
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/platform.rb:125:in `assert_file'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/platform.rb:129:in `assert_executable'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:60:in `binary_path'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:49:in `initialize'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/w3c_bridge.rb:40:in `new'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/w3c_bridge.rb:40:in `initialize'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:52:in `new'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:52:in `for'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:88:in `for'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:13:in `browser'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:45:in `visit'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/session.rb:227:in `visit'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
     # ./spec/support/features/about_us_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'`enter code here`
```

The lists below are the challenges of mine trying to fix them.

①install geckodriver

```
git clone https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver
```

②give geckodriver path

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/geckodriver
```

Here is my own surroundings.

```
ruby version 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-linux]
rails version 4.1.1

gem lists
  * actionmailer (4.1.1)
  * actionpack (4.1.1)
  * actionview (4.1.1)
  * activemodel (4.1.1)
  * activerecord (4.1.1)
  * activesupport (4.1.1)
  * addressable (2.5.1)
  * arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
  * bcrypt (3.1.11)
  * bootstrap-sass (3.1.1.1)
  * builder (3.2.3)
  * bundler (1.14.6)
  * capybara (2.4.4)
  * capybara-webkit (1.14.0)
  * childprocess (0.7.0)
  * coffee-rails (4.0.1)
  * coffee-script (2.4.1)
  * coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
  * database_cleaner (1.3.0)
  * diff-lcs (1.3)
  * erubis (2.7.0)
  * execjs (2.7.0)
  * factory_girl (4.4.0)
  * factory_girl_rails (4.4.1)
  * faker (1.4.3)
  * ffi (1.9.18)
  * hike (1.2.3)
  * i18n (0.8.1)
  * jbuilder (2.6.4)
  * jquery-rails (3.1.4)
  * json (1.8.6)
  * launchy (2.4.3)
  * mail (2.5.4)
  * mime-types (1.25.1)
  * mini_portile2 (2.1.0)
  * minitest (5.10.2)
  * multi_json (1.12.1)
  * nokogiri (1.7.2)
  * polyglot (0.3.5)
  * public_suffix (2.0.5)
  * rack (1.5.5)
  * rack-test (0.6.3)
  * rails (4.1.1)
  * railties (4.1.1)
  * rake (12.0.0)
  * rdoc (4.3.0)
  * rspec-core (3.1.7)
  * rspec-expectations (3.1.2)
  * rspec-mocks (3.1.3)
  * rspec-rails (3.1.0)
  * rspec-support (3.1.2)
  * rubyzip (1.2.1)
  * sass (3.2.19)
  * sass-rails (4.0.5)
  * sdoc (0.4.2)
  * selenium-webdriver (3.4.0)
  * spring (1.7.2)
  * sprockets (2.12.4)
  * sprockets-rails (2.3.3)
  * sqlite3 (1.3.13)
  * thor (0.19.4)
  * thread_safe (0.3.6)
  * tilt (1.4.1)
  * treetop (1.4.15)
  * turbolinks (5.0.1)
  * turbolinks-source (5.0.3)
  * tzinfo (1.2.3)
  * uglifier (3.2.0)
  * websocket (1.2.4)
  * xpath (2.0.0)
```

I want to know how to solve them.
Is it possible to the browser tests like Firefox , Chrome and IE using capybara and selenium?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to clone the geckodriver project, you need to download the binary for your platform - https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases - uncompress it and copy it to somewhere in your path